# modify asp.net mvc view naming convention

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In asp.net mvc 3, [View()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460331.aspx) method will select a view to render by following this naming convention

```
\Views\Controller\Action.cshtml
```

How can I modify the naming convention so that it will return Views from:

```
\Views\Theme\Controller\Action.cshtml
```

`Theme` is obtained from Session

```
var theme = Session["SelectedTheme"] ?? "Default";
```

and here is the current folder structure

```
- ...
-Controllers
 |-HomeController
 |-AccountController
- ...
-Views
 |-ThemeABC
    |-Home
    |-Account
 |-ThemeXYZ
    |-Home
    |-Account
 |-Default
    |-Home
    |-Account
- ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this post](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/03/26/ASPNET-MVC-Implement-Theme-Folders-using-a-Custom-ViewEngine.aspx) very helpful. from his code, I just need to modify LocationFormats in constructor as follows.

```
public class AndraViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public AndraViewEngine()
    {
        base.ViewLocationFormats = new string[] { 
            "~/Views/{2}/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
            "~/Views/{2}/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };

        base.PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] {
            "~/Views/{2}/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
            "~/Views/{2}/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
    }

    /* the rest of the code in that post */
}
```